# Class imagick not found when ran from CLI

Tags: php, imagemagick, kohana, command-line-interface, imagick

```
$im = new imagick($file);
```

This line of code will work fine when ran from my browser, but when I try to run it from command line (CLI) then I get the following error...

> Class 'imagick' not found

Any ideas why it won't work from CLI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
sudo aptitude install make php5-dev php-pear
sudo aptitude remove php5-imagick
sudo aptitude install libmagick9-dev
sudo pecl install imagick
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

http://kvz.io/blog/2008/02/27/class-imagick-not-found/

Answer (score 2):

The php cli executable is seperate(as in, a seperate binary file) from what generally gets run through a webserver. So, they can be totally different php versions, with different php.ini files and different extensions compiled in/enabled.

Comment: I did try to explicitly run the php executable in MAMP under the version I was running and I still got the same error.  I proabably did something wrong though. I'll take another look.

Answer (score 0):

Run "php -i | grep include_path" and make sure that class file path is in there. If not, you can either add it in your script or your environment (bash profile).

Comment: When I run that it gives the directory of MAMP's php.  I'm not sure where the class path is.  I installed imagick using PECL.  I followed [this guide](http://thoomtech.com/post/8832473042/mamp-imagemagick-lion)

Comment: Run the following command "which php" to see which instance of PHP you're running. If it returns "/usr/bin/php" it's likely you're running a different php installation.

Comment: which php says ...
    /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.2.17/bin/php

Comment: You can use the following in your script and point to your imagick file location. `<?php
$path = '/usr/lib/pear';
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $path);
?>`

Comment: That path didn't work.  I check that path on my Mac and that "pear" directory doesn't exist.