# Imagick module missing when installing with composer

Tags: php, apache, xampp, imagick

I have been trying to install PHP imagick extension on Xampp for Windows without success.

I succeeded to install Imagick (I can see it with `phpinfo()`) by installing `.dll` files and setting `php.ini` to use this dll extension.

But when I try to install with Composer or when I use PHP, I get the message

> PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_imagick.dll

I cannot install my own application on my computer.

Can someone help me ?

My phpinfo result:
[image: My phpinfo result]

Comment: Doesn't Composer effectively run in `cli` mode? Does that use the same *php.ini* file (I've a feeling it doesn't have to)? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10624582/class-imagick-not-found-when-ran-from-cli

Comment: Yes composer is run in cli mode. php --ini return : Configuration File (php.ini) Path: C:\WINDOWS
Loaded Configuration File:         C:\xampp\php\php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
 Does thath mean I should have a php.ini in C:\WINDOWS ? Tht php.ini file I used is C:\xampp\php\php.ini

Comment: *Sounds* like it should be OK, at least as far as retrieving a working *php.ini* file as it's loaded the same one from the command line as it would use from the web server... and you know that works as it appears in your `phpinfo()` output...

Comment: yes I kow that it should be ok.... I'm about to give it up....

Comment: You've probably already found this as it's linked from another SO question, but: http://hrt0kmt.hatenablog.com/entry/2015/05/27/170608 - the bit about setting the `MAGICK_HOME` Windows environment variable caught my eye though...

Comment: @CD001 you are talking about the "Configuration File (php.ini) Path C:\WINDOWS" ? I have no php.ini there, but only one php.ini is loaded, the one I updated.

Comment: Nope - there was something in that article about setting an Windows Environment Variable called `MAGICK_HOME` (in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER > Environment`) that points to the install dir (probably something like `C:/progra~1/imagic~1`)... I guess when using Imagick on PHP via a webserver that variable is set for you, but not with cli... I'm not certain though, I've only used Imagick from PHP running on a web server using the `exec()` function.

Comment: @CD001yes I tried to do this, but without success. Now I'm trying to install older packages from https://pecl.php.net/package/imagick, but I still get the same error message...

Comment: Thanks evrybody for your help. As I was late, I chose to go on Linux to avoid thin kind of problems. I hope this will be more stable and easy to work than Windows.